# Nulls within a CASE Statement

Tags: sql, case, case-when

I'm having an issue returning a value when the other values are `NULL`.

My SQL is as follows:

```
select id
, CASE WHEN value1 IS NOT NULL THEN value1
       WHEN value1 IS NULL THEN value2
       WHEN value1 IS NULL AND value2 IS NULL THEN value 3
       END
from ('table containing these values')
```

It successfully displays `value 2` when `value 1` is `NULL` but in the third `case` when both `value1` and `value2` are `NULL`, it has just been returning a blank.

Is there some restructuring of the `CASE WHEN` statement needed?

Comment: You need to swap the second and third `case`. If `value1` is null, the third one is never evaluated.

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should just use `coalesce`:

```
select coalesce(value1, value2, value3)
```

The correct form for your `case` is:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN value1 IS NOT NULL THEN value1
             WHEN value2 IS NOT NULL THEN value2
             ELSE value3
        END)
```

Comment: The restructuring to the correct form of the case statement solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The third case is never used, because the first and second cases are each others complements, so they cover all possibilities.

Change the order, so that you check the third case before the second:

```
select id
, CASE WHEN value1 IS NOT NULL THEN value1
       WHEN value1 IS NULL AND value2 IS NULL THEN value3
       WHEN value1 IS NULL THEN value2
       END
from ('table containing these values')
```

However, two of the conditions are superflous, as you know that `value1` is always `null` if it gets past the first condition:

```
select id
, CASE WHEN value1 IS NOT NULL THEN value1
       WHEN value2 IS NULL THEN value3
       ELSE value2
       END
from ('table containing these values')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the order you are applying your CASE options, try:

```
select id
, CASE WHEN value1 IS NULL AND value2 IS NULL THEN value 3
       WHEN value1 IS NOT NULL THEN value1
       WHEN value1 IS NULL THEN value2
       END
from ('table containing these values')
```